# Unit test method mocking IList

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I'm trying to mock the following method **TryGetApns**:

```
    private readonly Func<string, ICommunicationClient> _communicationFactory;

    public CommunicationApiFacade(Func<string, ICommunicationClient> communicationFactory)
    {
        _communicationFactory = communicationFactory;
    }

    public IList<ApnResponse> TryGetApns(string tenant)
    {
        GetApnsResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            var communicationApiClient = _communicationFactory(tenant);
            response = communicationApiClient.JctConfigurationService.GetApns();
        }
        catch (HttpException e)
        {
            ...
        }

        return response?.Apns ?? new List<ApnResponse>();
    }
```

with the following test:

```
    private Mock<ICommunicationApiFacade> _communicationApiFacade;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture()
            .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

        _communicationApiFacade = _fixture.Freeze<Mock<ICommunicationApiFacade>>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void RunJctTests_WhenJctIsInAPrivateNetwork_ShouldReturnAPassedTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var jctApn = _fixture.Create<string>();
        var message = _fixture.Build<JctLoggedIn>()
            .With(x => x.ApnFromDevice, jctApn)
            .Create();

        var response = _fixture.Build<ApnResponse>()
            .With(x => x.IsPrivateApn, true)
            .With(x => x.ApnName, jctApn).Create();

        _communicationApiFacade.Setup(x => x.TryGetApns(string.Empty))
            .Returns(new List<ApnResponse> { response });

        var subject = _fixture.Create<NetworkProviderTestRunner>();

        // Act
        var result = subject.Execute(message);

        // Assert
        Assert.That(result.Result, Is.True);
    }
```

and this is the **NetworkProviderTestRunner** class:

```
    private readonly ICommunicationApiFacade _communicationApi;

    public NetworkProviderTestRunner(ICommunicationApiFacade communicationApi)
    {
        _communicationApi = communicationApi;
    }

    public JctTest Execute(JctLoggedIn message)
    {
        var apns = _communicationApi.TryGetApns(message.Tenant);

        var jctApn = apns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApnName == message.ApnFromDevice);

        if (jctApn != null)
        {
            var privateApn = apns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PublicApnId.Equals(jctApn.Id));
            if (privateApn != null || jctApn.IsPrivateApn)
                return new JctTest { Result = true };
        }
        return new JctTest { Result = false };
    }
```

**JctLoggedIn** class:

```
public class JctLoggedIn : Message
{
    public string Imei { get; set; }
    public string SimCardIdFromDevice { get; set; }
    public string SimCardIdFromStorage { get; set; }
    public string ApnFromDevice { get; set; }
    public string ApnFromStorage { get; set; }
    public string FirmwareFromDevice { get; set; }
    public int DeviceTypeFromStorage { get; set; }
    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

but for some reason I always get back an empty list. I've tried to populate the list in the SetUp and also defining the output there but I's always the same. Any help?

Comment: Can you post the code of NetworkProviderTestRunner? As per your setup, TryGetApns will return the value you setup only when the tenant is empty string. It is worth checking whether you pass the correct value as per the setup.

Comment: It's done @Mani

Comment: Please also post `JctLoggedIn` so that we can see whether `Tenant` is writable or not. On the other hand, you can delete the first block of code, since you're replacing all of that with a test double.

Comment: Just found out that the Tenant field was the key! After filling it the test worked. Thank you @MarkSeemann to point that out and thank you everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could explicitly omit the `Tenant` property when building the `message` object, you could also change the Mock setup to this:

```
_communicationApiFacade.Setup(x => x.TryGetApns(message.Tenant))
    .Returns(new List<ApnResponse> { response });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
_communicationApiFacade.Setup(x => x.TryGetApns(string.Empty))
        .Returns(new List<ApnResponse> { response });
```

is telling the mock to return the list containing response when TryGetApns is called with an empty string for the tenant parameter.

What is the value of message.Tenant after message is created by this line:

```
var message = _fixture.Build<JctLoggedIn>()
        .With(x => x.ApnFromDevice, jctApn)
        .Create();
```

If it is not string.empty, your mock will not return the reponse list.

Comment: This would result in it either returning `null` is the mock is in `Loose` mode or throw an exception if it's in `Strict` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var response = _fixture.Build<ApnResponse>()
            .With(x => x.IsPrivateApn, true)
            .With(x => x.ApnName, jctApn).Create();
```

with

```
var response = _fixture.Build<ApnResponse>()
            .With(x => x.Tenant, String.Empty)
            .With(x => x.IsPrivateApn, true)
            .With(x => x.ApnName, jctApn).Create();
```

if Tenant is writable.

If the property is writable, AutoFixture will create an object with non-empty value for Tenant without explicitly setting up what you want.

Comment: I think that `Tenant` is a property on `JctLoggedIn`, not `ApnResponse`. Granted, it's not entirely clear from the OP...